# is it possible for a php script to stop at a certain point and resume executing from before that?

Tags: php, execute, resume

i don't know if this can be done using php but it would be awesome for me if it did and php is pretty powerful so i think it is possible and i just can't figure out how.

i know that a php file is executed from top to bottom but i would like to know if there is a way of stopping the execution at some point to then resume it on a later occasion or is there a way of reaching a certain part of it and then resuming from a part that is before it or something like that?

i know how to make this if i simply put each individual block of code on a separate php file, in this way it will stop because it reached the end of the file and if something happens it will resume from another file so it makes pretty much the same thing, but i would like to make a php script that would behave like this but contained in 1 php file.

i don't need code examples i just need a nod in the right direction, like, some function names or something that could be useful to serve this purpose.

Comment: Could you provide more of an example of *why* you want this kind of functionality? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: i am trying to figure out a good clean way of doing a script that executes certain blocks of code based on a sequence of user input information. this probably doesn't help and what i'm asking for could be used for literally millions of different things. and as i told before i can already have thins kind of functionality but in a messy and pretty complicated way that involves many files and a huge headache for me

Comment: Stopping and starting is controlled by signals on Unix. I don't think you can control where in your code the execution pointer will be. Debuggers offer invasive control, via breakpoints etc; but I have a hard time seeing how driving your code from the drbugger would make anything simpler. Probably you haven't been very good at explaining what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to do things based on user input, you should probably either:

1. Structure your program as a web application, such that each bit of user input spawns a new request to the page with the block of code that input should execute, or...
2. Use a different language than PHP.

Assuming you're doing #1, it's not all that hard to have a particular GET parameter that specifies what "step" you're on in the interaction - for instance, say you have a sequence of `"A <user input> B or C <user input> D or E"`. You could have a URL scheme that looks like this:

```
/app/code.php - this runs the code block A
/app/code.php?step=B or /app/code.php?step=C - this runs either code block B or C
/app/code.php?step=D or /app/code.php?step=E - this runs either code block D or E
```

where the links/Javascript/whatever on the served pages allow choosing which page loads next. Your PHP file would look something like this:

```
if(!isset($_GET['step'])) {
    // code block A
} elseif($_GET['step'] == 'B') {
    // code block B
} elseif($_GET['step'] == 'C') {
    // code block C
} elseif($_GET['step'] == 'D') {
    // code block C
} elseif($_GET['step'] == 'E') {
    // code block C
} else {
    // error, invalid step specified
}
```

You could also simply split the steps up into different PHP files. Which approach would be best probably depends on how much functionality is shared between the different options, and how much is different - if lots is shared, a single file might be easier; if most is different, separate files are probably simpler.

Comment: i thought of that method before and ruled it out because it wasn't perfect and on php usually there's a function for everything but that answer made me rethink my options because i'm searching for hours for something useful and really that's the only way i found so far to be best. thank you for that

Comment: Don't worry about what's "perfect", worry about what's "efficient". Does it get the task done in a way that is maintainable? Then it's fine.